# Prevent Brute-Force like DoS attack in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a situation where hacker started brute-force attack to a web site. The script will block a brute-force after 3 attempts ([example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/290000-limiting-login-attempts/)), but checking quantity of attempts also connecting to MySQL, too! Also, we need to call a query to get this quantity.

Am I right? If hacker will call this function, server would be DoSed?

I know that we can limit max connections to MySQL, but then other users won't be able to login?

How to grant a connection to MySQL every 10 seconds while guy isn't connected?

Comment: You won't be preventing users to login using a connection MAX, you will be putting them in a queue based on first requested first served basis. If your concerned about brute force attacks your better of using Fail2ban which will throttle repeat offenders without having to have noticable impact on other users. Using a proxy service such as Cloudflare will also limit these attacks.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! A have a DDoS prevent system on my MikroTik router/firewall, but is there something acceptional use of scripts which I could use ?

Comment: You want to implement connection pooling so that no matter how many attempts are made, only a small number of database connections are needed and then re-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to some extent you are correct . And to get disconnection for MySql you can use session, and you can blacklist or whitelist IP addresses so that blacklisted IPs will be denied directly.

Comment: Hmm ... how could I do this with public site ? Imagine that on site are over 999 new people every minute.

Comment: @V.7 you can store the ip in DB once and white list or black list them so 3 attempts will be reduced to 1 attempt

Comment: Okay. Here's a solution, but isn't it a one more DB process which'll reduce a System resources ?